# unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 debug error

Tags: ios, xcode

> Ld
>   /Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Release-iphoneos/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary\ Options\ Signals normal
>   armv7
>       cd "/Volumes/BURHANMAC/FXApp/Binary Options Signals"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\
>   Signals/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac
>   -F/Volumes/BURHANMAC/FXApp/Binary\ Options\ Signals/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks
>   -F/Volumes/BURHANMAC/FXApp/Binary\ Options\ Signals/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks
>   -F/Volumes/BURHANMAC/FXApp/Binary\ Options\ Signals/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks
>   -F/Volumes/BURHANMAC/FXApp/Binary\ Options\ Signals/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Volumes/BURHANMAC/FXApp/Binary\ Options\ Signals/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/Framework -filelist
>   /Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Release-iphoneos/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker
>   @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker
>   @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker
>   @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -dead_strip
>   -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -ObjC -lc++
>   -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework
>   FirebaseInstanceID -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMobileAds
>   -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OneSignal
>   -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework WebKit -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Release-iphoneos/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary_Options_Signals.swiftmodule
>   -framework Pods_Binary_Options_Signals -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Release-iphoneos/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals_dependency_info.dat -o
>   /Users/burhanmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Binary_Options_Signals-croehsvbunjihoauvwizpmkjowfj/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Binary\
>   Options\ Signals/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Release-iphoneos/Binary\ Options\
>   Signals.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary\ Options\ Signals

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Always explain your question properly so that people can understand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable the Bitcode in Project's Target -> Build Settings and search for 'bitcode' and make 'Enable Bitcode' value **NO**. Check the following screenshot.

[image]